# how can I pipe two echo in one line?

Tags: cmd

In a DOS command prompt :

```
echo b | echo a
```

results in `a` being displayed, but not `b`.  Why ?  How can I pipe 2 `echo` in one line ?

My overall goal is to launch several process from a Haskell program, and see when each starts and ends.  I would issue commands like :

```
echo start | myprogram | echo end
```

Comment: You might want to use the ampersand (`&`) to join the outputs (https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true contains the relevant documentation).

Answer (score 3):

See [Command Shell Overview](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true) article to learn how to run multiple commands in one line. There is a section **Using multiple commands and conditional processing symbols**

> command1 **&** command2
>
> Use to separate multiple commands on one command line. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command.
>
> command1 **&&** command2
>
> Use to run the command following && only if the command preceding the symbol is successful*. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then runs the second command only if the first command completed successfully*.
>
> *) If a command completes an operation successfully, it returns an exit code of zero (0) or no exit code.
>
> *[quote compacted by author of answer]*

...and several others.

Piping (redirecting command's output into another command's input) is not a solution here, just go with serial execution like shown above.

**Wait, there's more :)**

If you want to redirect the output for example to log, you would typically do:

```
echo a > out.txt & echo b >> out.txt & echo c >> out.txt
```

But there is a shorthand for that which uses parentheses mentioned in the above article:

```
(echo a & echo b & echo c) > out.txt
```

or equivalent (more readable with long commands)

```
 > out.txt (echo a & echo b & echo c)
```

As you can see, this spares you from combining of `>` and `>>` which is typically one more thing to check in the command.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan suggested, I'll use :

```
echo start & myprogram & echo end
```